# cant boot Windows 7 after boot-repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, windows-7

I originally have windows  7 64 bits, then I tried to dual-boot with Ubuntu 13.04.
but after installation my computer was only able to boot Windows (Ubuntu was not there as option).

So I boot from Ubuntu Live CD and ran boot-repair. After this, computer startup with Ubuntu only. Windows is no longer accessible. 
How can I fix it? I want to be able to run both OS.

My boot-info is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5620195/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Try again](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). But this time pay more attention at the number in `/dev/sdaX` where `X` should be an *specific* number,  in your case I think it is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i ran boot-repair again. windows is bootable now.

Comment: @Will Also, you can add more information, like what you did this time that you didn't in the first one..